# Unable to tell what port Logstash is bound to or listening on when started normally

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

My logstash version is:

```
# /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --version
logstash 2.2.4
```

it is configured to receive input from port 5044 according to the filebeat file:

> /etc/logstash/conf.d/02-beats-input.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

I have set ssl to false as I am not using it

but when I start the logstash service normally with systemctl it start and checking the status confirms it is running

```
   systemctl status logstash
    ● logstash.service - LSB: Starts Logstash as a daemon.
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash)
       Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-07-18 19:14:51 BST; 15h ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 19965 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 19970 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
...
    logstash started
```

The problem is that logstash does not seem to be receiving input on port 5044. hosts sending filebeats encounter:

```
single.go:126: INFO Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp 192.72.0.92:5044: getsockopt: connection refused
```

when I check the port

```
# netstat  -an | grep 5044
```

I get nothing. So even though logstash is running, I can't tell what port it is bound to and listening on.

Also the firewall is stopped temporarily to investigate this.

The strange thing is that is I run logstash is debug mode like so:

```
# ./logstash --debug -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/02-beats-input.conf
```

I can see

```
# netstat -an | grep 5044
tcp6       0      0 :::5044                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 192.72.0.92:5044        192.168.36.70:53720     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 192.72.0.92:5044        192.72.0.90:45980       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 192.72.0.92:5044        192.72.0.90:45975       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 192.72.0.92:5044        192.72.0.90:45976       ESTABLISHED
```

or

```
# lsof -i :5044
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    15136 root    7u  IPv6 7191510      0t0  TCP *:lxi-evntsvc (LISTEN)
java    15136 root   33u  IPv6 7192379      0t0  TCP hostname:lxi-evntsvc->192.72.0.90:45975 (ESTABLISHED)
```

and the host sending filebeats can connect

```
 output.go:87: DBG  output worker: publish 7 events
2016/07/19 10:02:08.017890 client.go:146: DBG  Try to publish 7 events to logstash with window size 10
2016/07/19 10:02:08.038579 client.go:124: DBG  7 events out of 7 events sent to logstash. Continue sending ...
2016/07/19 10:02:08.038615 single.go:135: DBG  send completed
```

Please help point out what I may be doing wrong with this configuration. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a systemctl logstash reload ?

Comment: on CentOS 7, the command systemctl logstash reload returns
Unknown operation 'logstash' and systemctl reload logstash returns
Failed to reload logstash.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit logstash.service.

Comment: Ok. Have you checked that your .conf file is  parsed and loaded ?

Comment: How can I check that please?

Comment: @pi. To check if a config file is loaded, a crude solution is to add an error in the configuration file (like an invalid option). Then you start Logstash, it should failed with sthg like `"Error: Something is wrong with your configuration."`

Comment: I think I got a hint from your previous suggestion regarding the possibility of the files not getting read. Following that trail, it looked like there was a permission issue with the files in conf.d not getting read when logstash was started. With modified permissions on this and also on the logstash.log file, a 2 day which ought to have been a 2 minute search was sorted. It would have been good if there was a permission message in the logs somewhere. Thanks for the hint @LiGhTx117

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hing provided by @LiGhTx117

I think

The startup script used by logstash in:

> /etc/init.d/logstash

has the following variables among others:

```
LS_USER=logstash
LS_GROUP=logstash
LS_HOME=/var/lib/logstash
LS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/logstash
LS_LOG_FILE="${LS_LOG_DIR}/$name.log"
LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
```

The ownership and permission on these seem to be the issue.

> I ensured that the directories where recursively accessible to the
>   user logstash  as well as the group logstash

and

> Then I also ensured that the log_file: logstash.log was writeable by
>   the user/group logstash

restarted logstash